# Is CartoDB a CMS for maps?

Tags: web-mapping, web-gis, content-management-system

I test cartodb with some data and I found it very useful. I found this instructions for installing cartodb locally in github [What is CartoDB?](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb) and I try to understand if cartodb is a CMS for maps.

Is like the joomla but for maps?

I mean can I install it and use it like the joomla?

The https://cartodb.com/ web site is just a host service for maps?

Answer (score 3):

No CartoDB isn't a CMS for maps. It's a platform to build map based visualisations. For a CMS for maps checkout [GeoNode](http://geonode.org/).